# Having issues with Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code giving me also Signing Identity: "-"

Tags: c++, xcode, grpc, codesign

I'm learning how to code and I'm at a lesson where I'm building a "messaging app" called FlashChat, I've done everything according to my class but a couple of days ago I pressed Command B after I ran the app on simulator, and the following issue kept showing up and I haven't been able to fix it:

CodeSign /Users/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flash_Chat_iOS13-bccxjpmgzvggxgetotmpidocaviy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++/grpcpp.framework (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/Desktop/Development/Flash-Chat-iOS13/Pods
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flash_Chat_iOS13-bccxjpmgzvggxgetotmpidocaviy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++/grpcpp.framework
```

/Users/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flash_Chat_iOS13-bccxjpmgzvggxgetotmpidocaviy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++/grpcpp.framework: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

I have tried everything from previous threads from checking KeyChain to verifying files, check bundle identifiers, signing licenses and all other suggestions related to anything written on my issue, any other ideas?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Update all the pods.
2. Run this command from the terminal.

> $ xattr -cr /Users/user_name/Desktop/Lab/Flash-Chat-iOS13/Pods/gRPC-C++

3. Go to ~Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. Delete all the folders present in that. The issue might be because Xcode is trying to run a older version of the code.

I am also running the same Flash Chat app from Udemy class. The above steps fixed the issue for me.
Start by trying with step 3 directly. If that doesn't work try all the 3 steps in the sequence.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, my Mac needed maintenance, I will look in to it once the Mac is sorted but thank you!!!